# Why does this nested list comprehension work?

Tags: python

This code works:

```py
>>>matrix = [[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]
>>>[num for row in matrix for num in row]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

But how? List comprehension is supposed to follow the pattern `[expression for item in iterable]`, and here the expression `num` should not be defined, or the iterable `row` should not be defined. What makes `matrix` the iterable and the second `for num in row` go back to defining the first `num`?

Comment: Think of it as a convenient way of writing two nested for loops.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confusing python list comprehension](//stackoverflow.com/q/19304238/90527)

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions can contain multiple `for` loops. They do not need to follow `[expression for item in iterable]`, they can have as many nested `for` loops as needed. The name of all of the values being created by the loop(s) can be accessed at the first expression of the list comprehension. Thus that is why something like `[num for row in matrix for num in row]` works because the first expression can basically be thought of as being at the end of the list comprehension instead of the start. As an example, `[num for row in matrix for num in row]` can also be written like so:

```
matrix = [[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]
list_ = []
for row in matrix:
    for num in row:
        list_.append(num)
```